# CSS problems with body height and footer sticking to bottom

Tags: html, css

In the code underneath, I've been running into some weird problems.

1) There's an 11px height black bar underneath the `mainContainer` div that just won't disappear. Even when giving the body element absolute position with top, left, right, bottom set to 0. This is causing a scrollbar for no reason at all.

2) The footer is always supposed to stick to the bottom but should never overlapse the `mainBody` div. To achiev this I gave it an absolute position and made it a child of the `mainContainer` div with a relative position. But it'll still overlapse the `mainBody` div up to a certain height.

I've been trying to fix these problems myself for a while now, but I just can't figure it out. So now I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:"Glass Antiqua";
    src: url("GlassAntiqua-Regular.ttf");
}

body {
 font-family: Glass Antiqua;
 color: White;
 font-size: 50px;
 background-color: black;
}

header #logo h1 {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}

nav ul {
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 margin-top: 0;
 background: #234e60; 
 background: linear-gradient(top, #234e60 0%, #245163 100%);  
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #234e60 0%, #245163 100%); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #234e60 0%,#245163 100%); 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 padding: 0 20px;  
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
 font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul:after {
 content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
 margin-left: 8px;
}

nav ul li {
 float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
 background: #193e4e;
 background: linear-gradient(top, #193e4e 0%, #1a4050 40%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #193e4e 0%, #1a4050 40%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #193e4e 0%,#1a4050 40%);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
 color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
 display: block; padding: 25px 35px;
 color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
 bottom: 0;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}

#mainContainer {
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 width: 830px;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #377a96;
 position: relative;
}

#logo {
 background: url(http://www.icecub.nl/images/banner_bats.png);
 height: 130px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: center;
}

#hr_lines {
 width: 100%;
 height: 3px;
 background: white;
 position: relative;
}

#hr_blue {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 background: #234e60;
}

#mainBody {
 height: 500px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

#img_footer {
 width: 830px;
 height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
 <header>
  <div id="logo">
   <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="hr_lines">
   <div id="hr_blue"></div>
  </div>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a><li>
    <li><a href="introductie.html">Introductie</a></li>
    <li><a href="opleiding.html">Mijn Opleiding</a></li>
    <li><a href="werk.html">Eigen Werk</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <div id="mainBody"></div>
 <footer>
  <img src="http://www.icecub.nl/images/boo.png" id="img_footer" alt="Afsluiting" />
 </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to fix it just by removing `position: relative` from your `#mainContainer` div...

Comment: @Joum If I remove that, it will allow the footer to overlapse the mainBody completely. Just try resizing your browser to something smaller and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it... Other people's answers might cover your issue, but if you don't mind, I'd like to point you in the direction of getbootstrap.com ... it seems to me that much of what you wanna do is already very well covered by them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `line-height: 0px;` to the footer - this will avoid any additional space below the footer image (which produces the overflow).

Also, give the `#mainContainer` a padding-bottom of ca. 160px to avoid overlapping of the footer and change its the min-height to `calc(100% - 160px)`:

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:"Glass Antiqua";
    src: url("GlassAntiqua-Regular.ttf");
}

body {
 font-family: Glass Antiqua;
 color: White;
 font-size: 50px;
 background-color: black;
}

header #logo h1 {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}

nav ul {
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 margin-top: 0;
 background: #234e60; 
 background: linear-gradient(top, #234e60 0%, #245163 100%);  
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #234e60 0%, #245163 100%); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #234e60 0%,#245163 100%); 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 padding: 0 20px;  
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
 font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul:after {
 content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
 margin-left: 8px;
}

nav ul li {
 float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
 background: #193e4e;
 background: linear-gradient(top, #193e4e 0%, #1a4050 40%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #193e4e 0%, #1a4050 40%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #193e4e 0%,#1a4050 40%);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
 color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
 display: block; padding: 25px 35px;
 color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
 bottom: 0;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 0px;
}

#mainContainer {
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 160px;
 width: 830px;
 min-height: calc(100% - 160px);
 background: #377a96;
 position: relative;
}

#logo {
 background: url(http://www.icecub.nl/images/banner_bats.png);
 height: 130px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: center;
}

#hr_lines {
 width: 100%;
 height: 3px;
 background: white;
 position: relative;
}

#hr_blue {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 background: #234e60;
}

#mainBody {
 height: 500px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

#img_footer {
 width: 830px;
 height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
 <header>
  <div id="logo">
   <h1>Welcome header</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="hr_lines">
   <div id="hr_blue"></div>
  </div>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a><li>
    <li><a href="introductie.html">Introductie</a></li>
    <li><a href="opleiding.html">Mijn Opleiding</a></li>
    <li><a href="werk.html">Eigen Werk</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <div id="mainBody"></div>
 <footer>
  <img src="http://www.icecub.nl/images/boo.png" id="img_footer" alt="Afsluiting" />
 </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the first problem. Now I still have to figure out why the footer overlapses the mainBody div instead of creating a scrollbar.

Comment: Give the #mainContainer a padding-bottom of ca. 160px - that should help.

Comment: I added what i wrote in the comment to my answer, so also that part is fixed now.

Comment: another edit - forgot to fix the height of the container - see edited answer

Comment: You're right, it prevents the overlapping, but it also creates a 160px gap between the mainBody and the footer somehow.

Comment: I seem to have solved the issue by removing the footer from the mainContainer and setting it to a relative position instead. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: aah just edited my answer too late, but glad it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem 1 by setting the image to fit as a block in your footer div :

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#img_footer {
    width: 830px;
  display: block;
    height: 150px;
}
```

see jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/vupm4fww/6/

edit for problem 2 just set position relative to your footer and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `overflow: hidden` to your footer, or just adjust the height of it (since the `150px;` is messing it up)

https://jsfiddle.net/8o9ufozs/